# Find website accounts related to my email address

Tags: account-management

Is there a way, perhaps using another web app, to know which sites I have accounts on? My Gmail account exists for almost 11 years, and over the years I've signed up on tens, or maybe even hundreds, of websites (a lot of which are already dead).

There are similar questions out there, but in all of them the answer is to log into Google and check the list of authorized apps. That's the easy case. In many cases, you just give your email address to the site as the username.

Comment: Not exactly responding your question, but a password manager does help to keep track of your accounts.

Comment: @Raisen that's true, and I have a large list in my saved passwords db. However, not all of the sites are there. Some I registered with another browser, another computer/phone, some just didn't trigger the password saver.

Comment: Not affiliated with them at all, but I've been using Lastpass for some years  and it has, like you said, hundreds, if not thousands, of accounts I signed up for.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best chance is to search for email address verification messages from the websites that your registered.

Use keywords like

registration confirmation
verify e-mail address
...